# Using Acronis Uinversal Restore, it's asking for a driver, where can I download it from?

Tags: windows-server-2003, xen, citrix

I'm trying to build a new windows farm, and I'm using Acronis True Image to restore clean 2003 images to a VM, (XEN, running under CentOS).

Towards the end I get this image, (below)
[image: PCIDEVICE]

which is to install the missing drivers. I look up the device, and it comes up as a Citrix XenServer PV SCSI Host Adapter -- I am at a loss as to where I can get this driver. Any assistance appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This driver turned out to not be required to get the VM up and running. I was able to install the driver once the vm was already up and running.